# Problem with getting selected OBJECT from dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a problem with getting selected objectfrom my list.

I bind collection of users to dropdownlist by:

```
 ddlContractors.DataSource = service.GetAllUsers();
                ddlContractors.DataTextField = "Name";
                ddlContractors.DataValueField = "Id";
                ddlContractors.DataBind();
```

It's working. 
But when I try getting selected object by:

```
var user = (User)ddlContractors.SelectedItem;
```

I get:

```
    (User)ddlContractors.SelectedItem   Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to 'GWDSite.GWDService.User'
```

How can I get object user from dropdownlist ? I can change type of my list control if it is necessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value field in the dropdown list is the field "Id" not the User object.  so 'SelectedItem' is returning the "Id" value -- not the object.  You can use that Id to lookup the User object (from session or cache or wherever you can keep it)

Answer (score 2):

You cant.

The SelectedItem is of type ListItem and you cannot just typecast a listItem back into your custom class i.e user.

You can only get the text or the value associated with the item that was selected via SelectedItem / SelectedValue

What you need to do is use that text / value and maybe retrieve your corresponding "User" object based on that text / value from somewhere (depending on how you are doing your state management).

Comment: in case of WPF /Silverlight, you can get the actual user object by uisng DataContext

Answer (score 1):

use SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem

WEB APPLICATION

As you are working with web app , approach i was describng will not work here.

you can get the ID of the selected item and use this ID as a parameter to retrive the object from the service layer but if the object is expensive to create than use caching to store your object and retrive it wheb needed.